# Bitnami Tomcat Stack GCE

Tags: tomcat, cloud, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Does Bitnami Tomcat stack has Google Cloud Debugger preinstalled. Among two available Tomcat stack in Cloud Engine, which one will be more suitable ?

https://console.developers.google.com/launcher/details/bitnami-launchpad/tomcatstack

or

https://console.developers.google.com/launcher/details/click-to-deploy-images/tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Debugger is pre-installed on the Google click-to-deploy Tomcat stack. However, choosing the click-to-deploy solution depends on your needs. You can have a clear overview on both deployments in the following Help Center articles [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/click-to-deploy-images/tomcat) [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/bitnami-launchpad/tomcatstack).

More information about manually deploying Cloud Debugger agent for Tomcat can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-debugger/debugging-tomcat).